# AngularJS broadcast -> on listener

Tags: angularjs

In one controller I have the following broadcast:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('handleCreatedUser', {message: 'Hallo'});
```

and in an other controller I have this one:

```
$rootScope.$on('handleCreatedUser', function(args) {
    alert('CreateUserResponseController : ' + args.message);
    });
```

and I always get as alert message: "undefined".
Actually I don't know what I am doing wrong. Has anyone any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/georapbox/angular-PubSub module !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) say

> The event listener function format is: function(event, args...)

so the args you want are the *second* argument, not the first so the following should work:

```
$rootScope.$on('handleCreatedUser', function(event, args) {
    alert('CreateUserResponseController : ' + args.message);
});
```